# Not able to execute a url from python script running via Cron

Tags: command-line, scripts, cron, python-2.7, aws

I have a script web.py which I am trying to run on the aws EC2 Instance using cron. It basically has these line of codes:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

If I run this script through putty using "python web.py" it does hit the browser. But same is not working if I run it via cron. My cron code is :

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/python  /home/web.py
```

The way I know its not working is there are few process which get executed once the url is hit. I can see those changes when I run the script through putty but not when I run it through cron.

I tried below modifications also but its not working.

```
*/10 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/python /home/web.py
*/10 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python /home/web.py
```

Also on echo $DISPLAY I get a null result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: code running from cron knows nothing about your logged-in GUI desktop session (sorry, my vocabulary just crashed: what's the word for that?) -- the python interpreter launched from cron cannot talk to your browser.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, because it looks like you've got the basics covered with `*/10 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python /home/web.py`. Could it be that yr "import webbrowser" in `web.py` does not correctly identify yr browser when run from `cron`.... ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a semicolon worked for me:

```
*/10 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/python /home/web.py
```